# Where CMake keeps it cache on Mac?

Tags: cmake

I have a build script for building gRPC/OpenSSL and I created a cache entry:

```
set(THIRDPARTY_INSTALL_PATH "${CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX}" CACHE STRING "Path for installing third-party OpenSSL and gRPC, if they are not found with find_package")
```

Originally there where `${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/third_party` instead of `${CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX}`.

My problem is that after cleaning a build folder (removing CMakeCache.txt of full cleanup) and rerunning cmake, this variable keeps it value equal to `${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/third_party`.

Where CMake can keep cache on MacOS? For Windows everything working well.

Comment: As far as I know, CMake stores cache variables in `CMakeCache.txt` on any platform. As removing the file doesn't help, than the problem is somewhere else... BTW, you may check content of `CMakeCache.txt` - it is a text file with simple structure.

Comment: @Tsyvarev yes, I checked it. The problem is that after running `cmake ..` this file is created with wrong entry. I call `cmake .. -G "Unix Makefiles" -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=123` but in `CMakeCache.txt the `THIRDPARTY_INSTALL_PATH` is equal to `${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/third_party`.

Comment: That means that some other line in your code assigns another value to the CACHE variable.

Comment: @Tsyvarev there is only [one entry](https://github.com/googleforgames/agones/pull/803/files#diff-5f850f216f5dcce37b4f14869bfc3b39R19). Without `FORCE` keyword it is not working.

Comment: Well, you may easy check that `CMakeCache.txt` is a primary storage for CMake cache by writting simple `CMakeLists.txt` which only sets a CACHE variable to some value. Remove the `CMakeCache.txt`, modify `CMakeLists.txt` to assign other value, rerun `cmake` and check that the value has been updated in the `CMakeCache.txt`.

Comment: BTW, using FORCE should update the CACHE wherever it is stored. As you don't observe this behavior, than again, it is **some other problem**. I would start from verifying that exactly you (modified) `CMakeLists.txt` is executed.

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't reproduced on a simple example. But after adding and removing `FORCE` it restored back to wrong value. I understand that it is "some other problem", but it doesn't help :(. I'm trying to localize problem. I'll update a question if I'll found an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: @Tsyvarev this variable was changed by an external script with "force". So there is no problems with CMake. Solution was simple - have a couple weeks of vacation. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `THIRDPARTY_INSTALL_PATH` cache variable was modified with "FORCE" by an external script. So there is no problem with CMake, it was a bug in local build scripts.